# how to change upper cases for all values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want to change upper cases for all values in dataframe, and use the following codes,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path1= "C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\ml-1m\\SELECT_FROM_HRAP2P3_SAAS_ZTXDMPARAM_201611291745.csv"
frame1 = pd.read_csv(path1,encoding='utf8',dtype = {'COUNTRY_CODE': str})
for x in frame1:
    frame1[x] = frame1[x].str.lower()
frame1
```

but i get the following error for this row:

```
 frame1[x] = frame1[x].str.lower()
```

error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

don't know the reason,

Comment: Probably because you have fields that are not of type string. You may want to try: `frame1[x] = frame1[x].astype(str).str.lower()`.

Comment: that's the reason, thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use applymap function.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'MovieName': ['LIGHTS OUT', 'Legend'], 'Actors':['MARIA Bello', 'Tom Hard']})
df2=df1.applymap(lambda x: x.lower())
print df1, "\n"
print df2
```

Output:

```
        Actors   MovieName
0  MARIA Bello  LIGHTS OUT
1     Tom Hard      Legend 

        Actors   MovieName
0  maria bello  lights out
1     tom hard      legend
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [str.lower](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) on Series object.

Support your DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(name=["HERE", "We", "are"]))

   name
0  HERE
1    We
2   are
```

Then lower all values and output:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.lower()

   name
0  here
1    we
2   are
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : 1.,
                   'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                  'C' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
                   'D' : np.array([3] * 4,dtype='int32'),
                   'E' : pd.Series(["TEST","Train","test","train"]),
                    'F' : 'foo' })

mylist = list(df2.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns)  # in dataframe    
                                                 #string is stored as object

for i in mylist:
   df2[i]= df2[i].str.lower()
```